# Selenium not finding Chrome Driver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In my project I used to access chromedriver like so:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = "/Users/J/Desktop/chromedriver"
```

however, driver_path is now deprecated, so I've switched to this way:

```
Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, driver_path: '/Users/J/Desktop/chromedriver'
```

I've also updated to the latest chromedriver.

However, for some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH.
```

But haven't I already downloaded it? I'm not sure why it's not able to find it.

Any ideas of why it's no longer working?

Comment: That should work, are you sure chromedriver is on the desktop? Does it run if you go to a terminal an type `/Users/J/Desktop/chromedriver` ?

Comment: It does run when I type that exact path into the terminal.

Comment: can you set `$DEBUG = true` and then try again, and update your question with the stacktrace?

Comment: place it on your PATH, like the error message says

Comment: As of the release deprecating the method you mentioned, you should only get that error message if you either didn't provide a `driver_path` argument or it can't be found in your path. If the `driver_path` argrument is wrong, it should present you with a different error message

Comment: Okay so I figured out that it errors on this line:  `@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome`. In the updated chrome driver is this still valid? This line runs after I set the driver_path.

Comment: I thought you said you were doing this instead `Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, driver_path: '/Users/J/Desktop/chromedriver'`

Comment: I'm not going to be able to help you unless you provide your entire startup code and/or the stack trace with `$DEBUG = true`. I tested this functionality extensively when I made the change

Comment: Like @CoreyGoldberg said, if you have it in your `PATH` (environment variable), it should work.